# Numpy: understanding the numpy array concept for row names

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Maybe a very vague question, but digging the links on numpy did not help me.

I need to do a similarity matrix calculation with following hierarchial clustering for binary array that look like this

```
name    val1    val2    val3    val4    val5
comp1   0   0   1   0   1
comp2   1   0   0   0   0
comp3   0   0   1   0   0
comp4   1   1   0   0   0
comp5   0   0   1   0   0
```

I don't understand the concept of row names in numpy. I can read the file like this

```
test = np.genfromtxt('test.b', delimiter='\t', names = True, dtype = None)
print type(test[0])
numpy.void
print test[0]
('comp1',0, 0, 1, 0, 1)
```

But how to take into account the row names (this info is very important)? Is it possible?

I suppose that the void is not a correct way of storing a binary array for further similarity matrix calculation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Numpy doesn't really support row names. It does support column names, through [structured arrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html). You could use something like `dtype=[('name', object), ('val1', int), ...]`. That could also be automated by reading the first line of the file, maybe.

What `genfromtxt` is giving you is simply an array of type `object`, where one column happens to contain strings and the others happen to contain integers – but all of them are stored inefficiently as Python objects, rather than in efficient formats.

You may be interested in [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/), which extends numpy matrices with support for labeled rows (among many other things). [`pandas.read_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_table.html?highlight=read_table#pandas.read_table) will handle your file nicely.