# Assigning field names to numpy array in Python 2.7.3

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy, user-defined-types

I am going nuts over this one, as I obviously miss the point and the solution is too simple to see :(

I have an np.array with x columns, and I want to assign a field name. So here is my code:

```
data = np.array([[1,2,3], [4.0,5.0,6.0], [11,12,12.3]])
a = np.array(data, dtype= {'names': ['1st', '2nd', '3rd'], 'formats':['f8','f8', 'f8']})
print a['1st']
```

why does this give

```
[[  1.    2.    3. ]
 [  4.    5.    6. ]
 [ 11.   12.   12.3]]
```

Instead of `[1, 2, 3]`?

Comment: I can't tell you why this doesn't work, but one solution is to use `np.rec.fromarrays` instead: `a = np.rec.fromarray(data, dtype= {'names': ['1st', '2nd', '3rd'], 'formats':['f8','f8', 'f8']})`. Which makes this question essentially a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220689/how-to-make-a-structured-array-from-multiple-simple-array .

Comment: yes. That is perfect! Still wondering why my example does not work. Pelase correct `fromarray` -> `fromarrays` in your example. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This answer may help, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18256220/numpy-understanding-the-numpy-array-concept-for-row-names, basically it seems you can't name rows in numpy but you can setup structured arrays with column names...

Comment: `data` needs to be a list of `tuples`.

Comment: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html#filling-structured-arrays

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [1]: data = np.array([[1,2,3], [4.0,5.0,6.0], [11,12,12.3]])
In [2]: dt = np.dtype({'names': ['1st', '2nd', '3rd'], 'formats':['f8','f8', 'f8']})
```

Your attempt:

```
In [3]: np.array(data,dt)
Out[3]: 
array([[(1.0, 1.0, 1.0), (2.0, 2.0, 2.0), (3.0, 3.0, 3.0)],
       [(4.0, 4.0, 4.0), (5.0, 5.0, 5.0), (6.0, 6.0, 6.0)],
       [(11.0, 11.0, 11.0), (12.0, 12.0, 12.0), (12.3, 12.3, 12.3)]], 
      dtype=[('1st', '<f8'), ('2nd', '<f8'), ('3rd', '<f8')])
```

produces a (3,3) array, with the same values assigned to each field. `data.astype(dt)` does the same thing.

But `view` produces a (3,1) array in which each field contains the data for a column.

```
In [4]: data.view(dt)
Out[4]: 
array([[(1.0, 2.0, 3.0)],
       [(4.0, 5.0, 6.0)],
       [(11.0, 12.0, 12.3)]], 
      dtype=[('1st', '<f8'), ('2nd', '<f8'), ('3rd', '<f8')])
```

I should caution that `view` only works if all the fields have the same data type as the original.  It uses the same data buffer, just interpreting the values differently.

You could reshape the result from (3,1) to (3,).

But since you want `A['1st']` to be `[1,2,3]` - a row of `data` - we have to do some other manipulation.

```
In [16]: data.T.copy().view(dt)
Out[16]: 
array([[(1.0, 4.0, 11.0)],
       [(2.0, 5.0, 12.0)],
       [(3.0, 6.0, 12.3)]], 
      dtype=[('1st', '<f8'), ('2nd', '<f8'), ('3rd', '<f8')])
In [17]: _['1st']
Out[17]: 
array([[ 1.],
       [ 2.],
       [ 3.]])
```

I transpose, and then make a copy (rearranging the underlying data buffer).  Now a view puts `[1,2,3]` in one field.

Note that the display of the structured array uses `()` instead of `[]` for the 'rows'.  This is clue as to how it accepts input.

I can turn your `data` into a list of tuples with:

```
In [19]: [tuple(i) for i in data.T]
Out[19]: [(1.0, 4.0, 11.0), (2.0, 5.0, 12.0), (3.0, 6.0, 12.300000000000001)]

In [20]: np.array([tuple(i) for i in data.T],dt)
Out[20]: 
array([(1.0, 4.0, 11.0), (2.0, 5.0, 12.0), (3.0, 6.0, 12.3)], 
      dtype=[('1st', '<f8'), ('2nd', '<f8'), ('3rd', '<f8')])
In [21]: _['1st']
Out[21]: array([ 1.,  2.,  3.])
```

This is a (3,) array with 3 fields.

**A list of tuples is the normal way of supplying data to `np.array(...,dt)`.**  See the doc link in my comment.

*You can also create an empty array, and fill it, row by row, or field by field*

```
In [26]: A=np.zeros((3,),dt)
In [27]: for i in range(3):
   ....:     A[i]=data[:,i].copy()
```

Without the `copy` I get a `ValueError: ndarray is not C-contiguous`

Fill field by field:

```
In [29]: for i in range(3):
   ....:     A[dt.names[i]]=data[i,:]
```

Usually a structured array has many rows, and a few fields.  So filling by field is relatively fast.  That's how `recarray` functions handle most copying tasks.

---

`fromiter` can also be used:

```
In [31]: np.fromiter(data, dtype=dt)
Out[31]: 
array([(1.0, 2.0, 3.0), (4.0, 5.0, 6.0), (11.0, 12.0, 12.3)], 
     dtype=[('1st', '<f8'), ('2nd', '<f8'), ('3rd', '<f8')])
```

But the error I get when using `data.T` without the copy is a strong indication that is doing the row by row iteration (my In[27])

```
In [32]: np.fromiter(data.T, dtype=dt)
  ValueError: ndarray is not C-contiguous
```

`zip(*data)` is another way of reordering the input array (see `@unutbu's` answer in the comment link).

```
np.fromiter(zip(*data),dtype=dt)
```

As pointed out in a comment, `fromarrays` works:

```
np.rec.fromarrays(data,dt)
```

This is an example of a `rec` function that uses the `by field` copy method:

```
arrayList = [sb.asarray(x) for x in arrayList]
....
_array = recarray(shape, descr)
# populate the record array (makes a copy)
for i in range(len(arrayList)):
    _array[_names[i]] = arrayList[i]
```

Which in our case is:

```
In [8]: data1 = [np.asarray(i) for i in data]
In [9]: data1
Out[9]: [array([ 1.,  2.,  3.]), array([ 4.,  5.,  6.]), array([ 11. ,  12. ,  12.3])]
In [10]: for i in range(3):
    A[dt.names[i]] = data1[i]
```