# Creating tuples with np.zero

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy

I might just be too stupid, but I need a fast version for this:

```
for i in range(0,4):
    c.append((0,0,0))

out: [(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0)]
```

I want to create a `zero filled tuple` in the **`shape of (xL,)`** with x being the amount of `(0,0,0)'s` ... I now do have three working solutions, none of them includes `np.zero`

Comment: Is the result supposed to be a list, a numpy array, a numpy structured array, or some thing else?  Why tuples instead of nested lists?

Comment: Is this related your previous question about a structured arrays - http://stackoverflow.com/q/32474115/901925

Comment: What is your ultimate goal here? Perhaps sparse matrix is what you need: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could go the structured array route:

```
In [304]: np.zeros((10,),dtype='i,i,i')
Out[304]: 
array([(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0),
       (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0)], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<i4')])
```

Strictly speaking these are not tuples - it just displays them as tuples.

But to get a list of tuples, just use `tolist`:

```
In [305]: np.zeros((10,),dtype='i,i,i').tolist()
Out[305]: 
[(0, 0, 0),
 (0, 0, 0),
 (0, 0, 0),
 ...
 (0, 0, 0),
 (0, 0, 0),
 (0, 0, 0)]
```

You can generalize the tuple length with a string generated with `','.join(['i']*3)`

For a non-structured approach I would use

```
[tuple(x) for x in np.zeros((10,3),int)]
```

In Python3 (especially) I prefer a list comprehension over the equivalent map: `list(map(tuple, np.zeros((10,3),int)))`.

Some timings (`L=10**5`):

structured array:

```
In [340]: timeit np.zeros((L,),dtype='i,i,i')
10000 loops, best of 3: 77.5 µs per loop
```

structured array converted to list of tuples:

```
In [341]: timeit np.zeros((L,),dtype='i,i,i').tolist()
10 loops, best of 3: 73.6 ms per loop
```

list of tuples from 2d array:

```
In [342]: timeit [tuple(x) for x in np.zeros((L,3),int)]
1 loops, best of 3: 223 ms per loop
```

pure python list of tuples:

```
In [343]: timeit [(0,0,0) for _ in range(L)]
100 loops, best of 3: 15.1 ms per loop
```

best list of tuples (`@swensel`):

```
In [344]: timeit [(0,0,0)]*L
1000 loops, best of 3: 429 µs per loop
```

If the ultimate goal is a list of tuples, stick with Python.

If the goal is a numpy structured array, go direct.

---

One thing to be wary about when using `[(0,0,0)]*L`; this achieves its speed by simply replicating the pointers.  Each entry in the list points to the same tuple.  With nested lists that can have serious problems:

```
x = [[0,0,0]]*L
x[1][1] = 3
```

changes every sublist.  With tuples this isn't so much an issue because they are immutable.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`numpy.zeros`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html) :

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.zeros(4*3).reshape(4,3)
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

And if you want it as tuple :

```
>>> map(tuple,np.zeros(4*3).reshape(4,3))
[(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)]
```

Or as @Divakar mentioned in comment as a more elegant way use a costume shape within `zeros` function :

```
map(tuple,np.zeros((4,3),dtype=int))
```

Comment: Or concisely `map(tuple,np.zeros((4,3),dtype=int))` maybe.

Answer (score 3):

If all you need is a list of tuples, you should stick with plain python, numpy won't speed things up because you need to translate back and forth between numpy arrays and lists/tuples.

This one should be fast enough:

```
def mkTuples(x, L):
    return [(0,)*L]*x
```

Comparison:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: x, L = 10**5, 4

In [3]: %timeit map(tuple, np.zeros((x,L)))
10 loops, best of 3: 177 ms per loop

In [4]: %timeit [(0,)*L]*x
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.07 ms per loop
```

If it has to be a numpy array, you could do this:

```
a = np.emtpy(x, dtype=tuple)
a[:] = ((0,)*L,)
```

Which roughly has the same speed as the plain python version but will result in a numpy array containing tuples.

I wish `np.full(x, (0,)*L, dtype=tuple)` would work but numpy WANTS to broadcast the second parameter even though it actually corresponds to one entry. Wrapping it into another tuple like above also doesn't work.

Comment: `dtype=tuple` is the same as `dtype=object`; the array just contains pointers to the tuple objects.

Comment: @hpaulj Yep, right... I noticed that too. Still, `np.full` officially takes a single scalar to fill the array. As far as I know scalars are either single elemented arrays or a plain number or object. So it should fill every slot with the very argument I provide. The fact that it doesn't, confuses me.

Comment: `np.full` creates an `empty`; it just uses `multiarray.copyto` instead of the `[:]=` that you use.  So even if worked it wouldn't be superior.

Comment: @hpaulj I know, I saw that in the stack trace. I didn't say it would be faster, but it would be more concise ;)

Comment: In the `full` context, a tuple is just like a list, something that can be converted to an array.  It's not a scalar, even if `dtype=object`.  `np.full((10,3),(0,1,2),dtype=object)` produces a normal 2d array.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this with [numpy.zeros](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html)

```
import numpy
a = numpy.zeros(shape=(5,2), dtype=numpy.int)
In [6]: a
Out[6]: 
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 0],
       [0, 0],
       [0, 0],
       [0, 0]])
```

And for **tuple**, you can do:

```
map(tuple, numpy.zeros(shape=(5,2)))
Out[3]: [(0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0)]
```

For `datatype` **int**, you can use:

```
map(tuple, numpy.zeros(shape=(5,2), dtype=numpy.int))
Out[4]: [(0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0)]
```